# Как в postgresql получить следующую строку таблицы с составным первичным ключом по первичному ключу предыдущей записи?

Tags: postgresql

Как в postgresql получить следующую строку таблицы с составным первичным ключом по первичному ключу предыдущей записи? Составной ключ может быть любой, не только из интов.

```
create table testobject6(
    pk1 int8,
    pk2 int8,
    pk3 int8,
    pk4 int8,
    pk5 int8,
    PRIMARY KEY(pk1, pk2, pk3, pk4, pk5)
);

insert into testobject6 
    (pk1, pk2, pk3, pk4, pk5) 
values 
    (1,2,3,4,5),
    (3,1,4,0,7),
    (2,9,5,5,6),
    (1,8,8,5,7),
    (1,9,0,0,8);

select * 
  from testobject6
 order by pk1, pk2, pk3, pk4, pk5;

select * 
  from testobject6
 where ... ??? -- допустим следующую за (2,9,5,5,6)
 order by pk1, pk2, pk3, pk4, pk5
 limit 1;
```

Comment: Писать сложное условие вроде `(pk1 > 2) or (pk1=2 and pk2>9) or (pk1=2 and pk2=9 and pk3>5) ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM testobject6
WHERE (pk1, pk2, pk3, pk4, pk5) > (2,9,5,5,6)
ORDER BY pk1, pk2, pk3, pk4, pk5
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Неплохо, не знал, что так можно. Но заточено под константы. Если попытаться усложнить запрос, чтобы джойнить текущую и следующую, то этот подход не будет работать без серьёзного усложнения запроса, которое перечеркнёт всю красоту `(pk1,...) > (val1,...)`

Answer (score 1):

```sql
 select * ,
  lead(pk1) over next_row as next_pk1,
  lead(pk2) over next_row as next_pk2,
  lead(pk3) over next_row as next_pk3,
  lead(pk4) over next_row as next_pk4,
  lead(pk5) over next_row as next_pk5
 from testobject6
 window next_row as (order by pk1, pk2, pk3, pk4, pk5 rows between current row and 1 following)
 order by pk1, pk2, pk3, pk4, pk5;
```